# Twitter OAuth 1.1 show.json fails while home_timeline.json succeed

Tags: cordova, twitter, oauth

I'm successfully retrieving result from home_timeline.json but using same oauth logic /users/show.json is failing (users/lookup too).

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

I'm adding user_id to the request, while using base url for signature.

Notice that home_timeline.json has required user context, while other endpoints don't require user context, but not sure if it's related.

Application is mobile phonegap (angular), and using $cordovaOauth.twitter to sign up user and retrieve oauth token.
I've tested using Postman and same thing happens. OAuth is valid for home_timeline.json, but when trying same logic and generate new OAuth for users/show.json, request fails as unauthenticated.

Here's code for generating signature

```
function createTwitterSignature(method, url) {
    var oauthObject = {
        oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
        oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(10),
        oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
        oauth_token: token.oauth_token,
        oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
        oauth_version: "1.0"
    };
    var signatureObj = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature(method, url,oauthObject, {},clientSecret, token.oauth_token_secret);
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = signatureObj.authorization_header;
}

var url ='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json';
//var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json';
//var user_id = token.user_id;
createTwitterSignature('GET', url);
//return $resource(url+'?user_id='+user_id).query();
return $resource(url).query();
```

Anyone has idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query params *MUST* be included in the OAuth signature.  Also POST requests of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded should include params from the body in the signature.

See https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures for more information

Comment: Thank you Yuri!
Adding params into signature solved the problem.
As it's GET request I've just added params to the URL when invoking service, but I'll keep in mind your advice for POST.
Ones again... Thank you!